# Use font per program

Tags: linux, phantomjs, puppeteer, fontconfig

I use phantomjs and puppeteer on the same system. I am using a font file to support emoji in PDF exports. phantomjs crashed when I use that font, but not chromium browser used in puppeteer. Is there any way I can load the font file specifically for chrome only without making the font apply system wide from `/usr/share/fonts`. I am on CentOS 7 machine.

Comment: If the presence of font is a problem in itself, then running Chrome as a different user (with sudo/gksudo/kdesudo) and planting font in that user's `~/.fonts` directory could be a solution. Extremely ugly one, but perhaps working.

Answer (score 1):

You can [convert](https://transfonter.org/) the font into a [web font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts), and then embed the font into the web page using [`page.addStyleTag()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddstyletagoptions):

```
await page.addStyleTag({
    'content' : `
        @font-face {
            font-family:'[font-name]';
            src:url('[font-file].woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('[font-file].woff') format('woff');
            font-weight:normal;
            font-style:normal;
        }
    `
});
```

Then, you can run [`page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) to download the web page as a PDF containing your custom font.

This will allow you to use the font on a case-by-case basis without needing to install it on your machine.